# Magento image upload filename doesn't save in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, magento

I am trying to add an additional image upload field to a gallery extension. The code for the extension controller is below. I've added an extra column to the database called galpic_popup_image with the same values as the existing galpic_image column.

I've managed to get the upload working, so images are saved on the server, however it isn't saving the filename in the database and therefore I can't call it on the frontend.

```
class ParadoxLabs_Gallery_Adminhtml_GalleryController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu('cms/gallery');
        $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Gallery'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Gallery'));

        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function editAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu('cms/gallery');
        $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Gallery'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Gallery'));

        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('gallery/adminhtml_gallery_edit'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function newAction()
    {
        $this->editAction();
    }

    public function saveAction()
    {
        if ( $this->getRequest()->getPost() ) {
            // Image uploading code modified from https://magento2.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/m1wiki/pages/14024884/How+to+create+an+image+or+video+uploader+for+the+Magento+Admin+Panel
            if(isset($_FILES['image']['name']) && (file_exists($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])))
            {
                try{
                    $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('image');
                    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
                    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
                    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                    $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'p_gallery' . DS ;
                    $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['image']['name']);
                    $data['image'] = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'p_gallery/'. $_FILES['image']['name'];
                }catch(Exception $e){}
            }
            else
            {
                if(isset($data['fileinputname']['delete']) && $data['fileinputname']['delete'] == 1){                   
                    $data['image_main'] = '';
                }
                else{
                    unset($data['image']);
                }
            }

            if(isset($_FILES['popup_image']['name']) && (file_exists($_FILES['popup_image']['tmp_name'])))
            {
                try{
                    $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('popup_image');
                    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
                    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
                    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                    $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'p_gallery' . DS ;
                    $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['popup_image']['name']);
                    $popupdata['popup_image'] = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'p_gallery/'. $_FILES['popup_image']['name'];
                }catch(Exception $e){}
            }
            else
            {
                if(isset($popupdata['fileinputname']['delete']) && $popupdata['fileinputname']['delete'] == 1){                 
                    $popupdata['popup_image_main'] = '';
                }
                else{
                    unset($popupdata['popup_image']);
                }
            }

            try {
                if( intval($this->getRequest()->getParam('id')) == 0 ) { // New
                    $model = Mage::getModel('gallery/gallery')
                        ->setGalpicId   ( $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')    )
                        ->setGalpicStore( $this->getRequest()->getParam('store') )
                        ->setGalpicDate ( date('Y-m-d', time()) )
                        ->setGalpicName ( $this->getRequest()->getParam('name')  )
                        ->setGalpicImage( $data['image']                         )
                        ->setGalpicPopupImage( $popupdata['popup_image']                         )
                        ->save();
                }
                else { // Edit
                    $model = Mage::getModel('gallery/gallery')
                        ->setGalpicId   ( $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')    )
                        ->setGalpicStore( $this->getRequest()->getParam('store') )
                        ->setGalpicName ( $this->getRequest()->getParam('name')  )
                        ->setGalpicImage( $data['image']                         )
                        ->setGalpicPopupImage( $popupdata['popup_image']                         )
                        ->save();
                }

                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Galpic was successfully saved'));

                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
                return;
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }

    public function deleteAction()
    {
        if( $this->getRequest()->getParam('id') > 0 ) {
            try {
                $model = Mage::getModel('gallery/gallery');
                $model->setGalpicId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
                    ->delete();
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Galpic was successfully deleted'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
            }
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }

    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('cms/gallery');
    }
}
```

And here is the form used to capture the data:

```
class ParadoxLabs_Gallery_Block_Adminhtml_Gallery_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        if (Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->isEnabled()) {
            $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setCanLoadTinyMce(true);
        }
    }

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
                'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
                'id' => 'edit_form',
                'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
                'method' => 'post',
            ));

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('gallery_form', array(
            'legend'      => Mage::helper('gallery')->__('Galpic'),
            'class'     => 'fieldset-wide'
          )
        );

        $fieldset->addField('galpic_name', 'text', array(
            'name'      => 'name',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('gallery')->__('Name'),
            'class'     => 'required-entry',
            'required'  => true,
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('galpic_image', 'image', array(
            'name'      => 'image',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('gallery')->__('Image'),
            'class'     => 'required-entry',
            'required'  => true,
        ));
        $fieldset->addField('galpic_popup_image', 'image', array(
            'name'      => 'popup_image',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('gallery')->__('Popup Image'),
            'class'     => 'required-entry',
            'required'  => true,
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('galpic_store', 'select', array(
            'name'      => 'store',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('core')->__('Store View'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('core')->__('Store View'),
            'required'  => true,
            'values'    => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_store')->getStoreValuesForForm(false, true),
        ));

        if (Mage::registry('gallery')) {
          $form->setValues(Mage::registry('gallery')->getData());
        }

        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

Comment: One problem I see is that $data is not declared. In the wiki in which your code is based, $data is declared as in the if statement:  if ($data = $this→getRequest()→getPost()). If you do that, then your variable $popupdata is redundant as the value popup_image will be contained in $data['popup_image'] and the delete image option will work. However, the above doesn't explain why the popup image is not saved in the DB without the code throwing error.

Comment: Thanks Kiatng, I will check that out. I'm still puzzled as to why the image url isn't saved in the DB. As you say, no errors are thrown at all, but seeing as I'm new to php I'm probably missing something simple :/

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I fixed it!

It was suggested to make sure the columns were in the same order as the controller saves the items so I did that. It didn't seem to have an effect (but it may have done).

I changed the second image upload code to the following (basically removed 'popup' from $popupdata as Kiatng suggested) above:

```
if(isset($_FILES['popup_image']['name']) && (file_exists($_FILES['popup_image']['tmp_name'])))
            {
                try{
                    $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('popup_image');
                    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
                    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
                    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                    $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'p_gallery' . DS ;
                    $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['popup_image']['name']);
                    $data['popup_image'] = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'p_gallery/'. $_FILES['popup_image']['name'];
                }catch(Exception $e){}
            }
            else
            {
                if(isset($data['fileinputname']['delete']) && $data['fileinputname']['delete'] == 1){                   
                    $data['image_main'] = '';
                }
                else{
                    unset($data['popup_image']);
                }
            }
```